# What can I do with Halo 4 and Xbox Smartglass?

Tags: halo-4, xbox-smartglass

The [Wikipedia article about Smartglass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xbox_SmartGlass) says that it is compatible with Halo 4 but I can't find any further information about it. Is there anything special I can do with Smartglass interacting with Halo 4?

Answer (score 1):

When controlling Xbox via iPhone SmartGlass, your [Halo Waypoint](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/) Service Record automatically loads via an app called [Halo 4 stats](http://www.halowaypoint.com/en-us/career/webappoverview).  I believe this is in Windows 8 "metro" format, but I'm not positive.
[image: Smartglass App Home - Halo 4]
[image: Smartglass Halo 4 Stats Loading]
[image: Smartglass Halo 4 Stats Loading 2]]
[image: Smartglass Halo 4 Stats]]

It has a lot of cool stats and such, which can be helpful while you are playing the game if you want to know what to focus on.  Especially during load screens and such.  The SmartGlass app "controller" does not appear to work with the game - but beating the Didact with your smartphone was probably never in the cards anyway.

Comment: When I connect my SmartGlass app and I'm playing Halo 4, I can't find the Waypoint Service Record. Do you know where in the app I can find it?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I added some pictures to hopefully illuminate.  Halo 4 stats is an app within Waypoint.  343 basically co-opted the name of the Bungie Waypoint app as their new forums/stats/etc website.  Does that clear things up?  There is no real time 2 screen interaction - but it does load your stats automatically.  Do you see something different with your Win 8 version of the app?

Comment: That is interesting. The Android app has the same interface, but I cannot get the "Halo 4 Stats" button to appear when Halo 4 is running. The Windows 8 version does seem to have the same "Halo 4 Stats" option, but I can't use it because my Win 8 device does not support touch (so it won't even run).

Comment: @murgatroid99 For the Android app, is it fully synced with your XBox? ie Do other apps load automatically when you switch games?  It could be that you just haven't set up your app to sync with your box yet (I don't remember exactly, but I think it assumes the same Live ID for both the app and the box).

Answer (score 0):

When Halo 4 is running, the version of Xbox Smartglass on Windows 8 will allow you to access your Halo 4 stats from the main app interface if your Windows 8 device supports touch.

The iPhone version of the app can access the same stats, but the Android version of the app does not have any special interaction with Halo 4.